# SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 gives "Multiple-step operation generated errors" error for simple query

Tags: c++, sql-server-ce, oledb, ado, sql-server-ce-3.5

I'm using a SQL Server CE database via Microsoft's OLEDB 3.5 SQL CE Driver.  Here's my connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=C:\Users\me\Desktop\test1.sdf
```

This query works fine:

```
SELECT Thing FROM OtherThing WHERE name = 'TextThing'
```

This query fails:

```
SELECT Foo FROM Stuff
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.
```

The only structural difference in the table themselves is that one has a text primary key and the other has a bigint identity field as a primary key.

What I've tried:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495  (neither of the resolution conditions are true for me)
- Switched the cursorLocation property from adUseClient to adUseServer (this caused none of my queries to work - same error).  That said, I think maybe I shouldn't give up on this one (thoughts?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the fact that the tables that caused that exception to be thrown were ones with fields of type nvarchar and sizes of 255.  I changed those to ntext or reduced the size to 100 and no exception was thrown.