# How do i correctly query a sql ce 4.0 database file using adodbapi?

Tags: python, sql-server-ce, adodbapi

I have the following method:

```
def open(self, filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        raise IOError("Cannot find Game Database file {0}").__format__(filename)

    connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0; 
               Data Source={0};".format(filename)
    conn = adodbapi.connect(connstr)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    query = "Select * from Patient;"
    curs.execute(query)
    results = curs.fetchall()
    for r in results:
        print r
```

When this runs, the following error is rased on curs.execute(query):

```
(<class 'adodbapi.adodbapi.DatabaseError'>, u"(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Cursor Engine', u'Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.', None, 0, -2147217887), None)\nCommand:\nSelect * from Patient;\nParameters:\n[]")
```

I can run this exact query in [compactView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/) successfully.

What obvious syntactic sugar am i not seeing?  ( running: win7 pro x64, python 2.7.x, pywin32 and adodbapi installed successfully.  The connection string seems to work -- i can connect and get a cursor just fine)

Answer (score 2):

Using adodbapi-2.6.0.7 I solved this using the following:

```
connection.connector.CursorLocation = 2
```

For example:

```
import adodbapi

file = r'FILEPATH'
connection_string = (
    'Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5; Data Source={};'.format(file))
print(connection_string)
connection = adodbapi.connect(connection_string)
connection.connector.CursorLocation = 2
connection.get_table_names()
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that one of the table columns you are selecting is of type NVARCHAR(N) where N is larger than 127 [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221821/getting-delphi-7-to-play-with-sql-server-compact-3-5)]. Using the server-side cursor will solve the problem.

```
conn.adoConn.CursorLocation = adodbapi.adUseServer
```