# Error as Object was open when connecting to datasource using database checkpoint in UFT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hp-uft

I created one datasource and tested the connection and it was successful.

When I am trying to connect to that particular datasource for querying it , I am getting this error message : `object was open`.

How to Resolve this error? And to which object it is referring to? I am trying to connect to Microsoft Sql Server 2008.

Comment: Look like this error is related to ms SQL server this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14222561/105104) could be helpful

Comment: Thanks.It got resolved, While creating checkpoint I was not giving where clause , thats why it was fetching 2lakhs records and was not allowing .After adding where clause it worked.